# How do I fix " 'tuple' object does not support item assignment " in my code?

Tags: python, tuples

```
import math  
def ListSqrRoot(nums):  
    n=len(nums)  
    for i in range(n):  
        nums[i]=math.sqrt(nums[i])  


def main():  
    nums=eval(input("Please enter a list of numbers:"))  
    print( "Before calling the function your list is:")  
    print (nums)  
    ListSqrRoot(nums)  
    print ("After calling the function your list is:")  
    print (nums)  

main()
```

Comment: You need to first turn it into a list before passing to your function. Tuples are immutable

Comment: use list as an alternative if you want the tuple object to be edited. What is the problem in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `eval(input("Please enter a list of numbers:"))` returns a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) which is immutable and you're trying to modify it here:

```
nums[i] = math.sqrt(nums[i])
```

It can be fixed by creating a `list` instead:

```
nums = [x for x in eval(input("Please enter a list of numbers:"))]
```

**Warning:** [eval is evil!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is that the expression you enter into eval, such as "1, 2, 3" are tuples, which are immutable, i.e., unable to be changed.

Additionally, using eval like this is dangerous, and can lead to some confusing errors. (What happens if you put in an empty list?) Python has plenty of nice string manipulation functions, so it is also completely unnecessary. Try,

```
line = input('enter numbers:')
nums = [int(s.strip()) for s in line.strip().split(',') if s]
```